# Runtime Issues with std::optional in GCC on M2 Mac

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, option-type, c++23

I have found what I believe to be a weird bug with `std::optional` in GCC on my macbook. I am hoping that someone can either show me that I'm wrong, or offer guidance about where to report it.

---

**Background:**

I recently decided that I wanted to learn more about monads, so I started following along with a presentation given at CppConn this past year. (Video [here](https://youtu.be/kZ8rbhGgtv4?si=KeDW9HnRAWWFa-C7) for those interested)

My environment is composed of:

```
Hardware: Apple M2 Macbook Air
OS:       Sonoma 14.2.1
GCC:      13.2.0
```

---

**Initial Problem:**

In the following code, I found that I was unable to catch the `std::invalid_argument` being thrown by `std::stoi`.

###### Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

std::optional<int> convertStrToInt(const std::string& s) {
    std::optional<int> ret;

    try {
        ret = std::stoi(s);
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "Caught bad str to int conversion!\n";
    }

    return ret;
}

int doubleValue(int v) {
    return v+v;
}

std::string convertIntToStr(int v) {
    return std::to_string(v);
}

std::optional<std::string> stringDouble(const std::optional<std::string>& opt) {
    return opt.and_then(convertStrToInt)
              .transform(doubleValue)
              .transform(convertIntToStr);
}

int main() {
    std::optional<std::string> result;

    std::optional<std::string> input_1("123");
    result = stringDouble(input_1);
    if ( result.has_value() )
        std::cout << "stringDouble's result for input_1: " << result.value() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "stringDouble has no result for input_1\n";

    std::optional<std::string> input_2("NaN");
    result = stringDouble(input_2);
    if ( result.has_value() )
        std::cout << "stringDouble's result for input_2: " << result.value() << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "stringDouble has no result for input_2\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

###### Compile:

```
g++-13 -std=c++23 std_opt.cpp
```

###### Output:

```
stringDouble's result for input_1: 246
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stoi
Abort trap: 6
```

---

**Concise Problem:**

Given the unexpected result above, I decided to make a more concise program to see if I could better determine the cause.

###### Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("why?!");
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "caught exception\n";
    }

    std::optional<std::string> some_opt("my val");

    return 0;
}
```

###### Compile:

```
g++-13 -std=c++23 exception_test.cpp
```

###### Output:

```
libunwind: _Unwind_GetTextRelBase - _Unwind_GetTextRelBase() not implemented
Abort trap: 6
```

It is also worth noting, that replacing line 11 above with any other, valid c++ code seems fine. E.g., putting a `std::cout` seems to work as desired.

---

**Testing in Linux:**

To see if this was just a Mac issue, created a container from the `gcc:13.2.0` image and copied the above code into it.

As you can see, it works as desired:

```
# uname -a
Linux 62b6636acd54 6.7.4-200.fc39.aarch64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Feb  5 23:05:56 UTC 2024 aarch64 GNU/Linux
# g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

# g++ -std=c++23 exception_test.cpp
# ./a.out 
caught exception
# g++ -std=c++23 std_opt.cpp 
# ./a.out 
stringDouble's result for input_1: 246
Caught bad str to int conversion!
stringDouble has no result for input_2
```

---

**What's Next**

So... am I missing something? Is this a bug? Is it a bug with GCC on Mac? Is it a bug in `libunwind`? Are the above two behaviors even part of the same issue? I am at a bit of a loss.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, could you try to link with `lld` instead of `ld`? Are you running Xcode? A version prior to 15 beta 6 perhaps?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I tried adding `-fuse-ld=lld` to my compile commands from above, and the results are the same. Thanks for the tip though! As for Xcode, I am not running it (at least, I don't think I am; I am new to Apple dev and haven't done anything with Xcode).

Comment: Ok, it was worth a shot :)

Comment: I'm having a similar error to you with `gcc` on MacOS Sonoma, `libunwind: _Unwind_GetTextRelBase - _Unwind_GetTextRelBase() not implemented`. I am now convinced that the new command-line tools release is extremely buggy, I've been having non-stop errors with compilation too in certain circumstances that shouldn't be there.